# Is the rotation in 2D done by vector addition, project, or rotation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, recreational-mathematics, self-learning

Looking at the two equations in the picture below, the clockwise rotation matrix is applied to them. However, the picture says the axes are rotated anti-clockwise by $ \theta$, Is this done by vector projection, vector addition, or rotation?

[image]

Comment: Consider $\tilde{x}_1$ and $\tilde{x}_2$ as two vectors. Then each of them is the sum of two components...

Comment: Each of them is the sum of two components...?? Uhmmmm, I think I understand what you say halfway through... I know you are saying vector addition...

Answer (score 2):

The rotation matrix 
$$\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta&\sin\theta\\-\sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{pmatrix}$$
rotates a vector clockwise by $\theta$. But that is equivalent as rotating the axis counterclockwise by $\theta$ and use the new coordinate system.

Consider a simple example, the vector $(1,0)$ becomes $(0,-1)$ if rotated clockwise by $90$ degrees. But that is equivalent as rotating the $xy$-axis counterclockwise (in which $x$ is pointing upwards, and $y$ is pointing to the left), and look at the original point now in the new $xy$-system, which is $(0,-1)$.

The following picture shows a clockwise rotation of vector $(x_1,x_2)$ to $(\tilde{x}_1,\tilde{x}_2)$.

[image]

We have 
$$\tilde{x}_1=r\cos(\phi-\theta)=r\cos\phi\cos\theta+r\sin\phi\sin\theta=x_1\cos\theta+x_2\sin\theta,\\
\tilde{x}_2=r\sin(\phi-\theta)=r\sin\phi\cos\theta-r\cos\phi\sin\theta=-x_1\sin\theta+x_2\cos\theta.$$

Now as I said, this is equivalent as rotating the axis counterclockwise:
[image]

In the new system $\tilde{x}_1\tilde{x}_2$, the original points have the coordinate just as above calculated.